# Sheets().ListObjects() returning 438 error

Tags: vba

I'm using a worksheet_change event on a given tab (Data) where I want to refer to a table on a different tab (Summary by Case). When refer to the table on sheet 2 using Sheets().ListObjects() I receive a 438 error stating the object doesn't support that property or method. The debugger "watch" function can however read the statement without error.

Any advice finding my error would be appreciated! Thanks!

Relevant sample code:

```
Dim byCase As Worksheet
Dim byCaseShName, byCaseTblName As String

byCaseShName = "Summary by Case"
Set byCase = Sheets(byCaseShName)
     
byCaseTblName = "Table3"
byCase.ListObjects (byCaseTblName)
```

Comment: That last line doesn't *do* anything though?

Comment: `Dim t As ListObject: Set t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary by Case").ListObjects("Table3")`

Comment: I oversimplified my sample code. It was actually byCase.ListObjects (byCaseTblName).range.rows.count, but I wasn't assigning that value to anything. 


Thank you for your help and I apologize for asking such a silly question.

Comment: Always safer to post the actual code than to simplify - that runs the risk of changing the problem

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: No problem  - glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

My last line wasn't doing anything as pointed out by Tim Williams.

Thanks for your help Tim and sorry for wasting your time!